# How to print drupal module version with drush 6.5.0

Tags: drush

Here's an example of a module in one of my make files:

```
projects[views][version] = "3.8"
projects[views][type] = "module"
projects[views][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[views][download][url] = "git://testurl.org/drupal/modules/views.git"
projects[views][download][tag] = "7.x-3.8
```

Drush 5.7.0 adds information about the module to every module .info file:

```
; Information added by drush on 2015-01-20
version = "7.x-3.8"
core = "7.x"
project = "views"
datestamp = "1421783211"
```

I can't find a way to append this information with Drush 6.5.0 and since I am using a git repo, the version is always missing from the .info file.

Is there a way to print that information with Drush 6.5.0?

Comment: Upgrading drush to 8.0.3 and using --force-gitinfofile flag did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to check all the info about a module. For this command is :

```
drush pmi module_name
```

This command provide info like this :

```
Extension        :  module_name                                                                         
 Project          :  module_name                                                                         
 Type             :  module                                                                                
 Title            :  module_name                                                                         
 Description      :  Improves Drupal's login system.                                                       
 Version          :  7.x-1.5                                                                               
 Date             :  2015-05-01                                                                            
 Package          :  Other                                                                                 
 Core             :  7.x                                                                                   
 PHP              :  5.2.4                                                                                 
 Status           :  enabled                                                                               
 Path             :  sites/all/modules/module_name                                                       
 Schema version   :  7000                                                                                  
 Files            :  none                                                                                  
 Requires         :  none                                                                                  
 Required by      :  module_name
 Permissions      :  none                                                                                  
 Configure        :  admin/config/system/module_name
```